# How to handle InvalidElementStateException in webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to perform drag and drop in Webdriver, and I am facing problem on running my test.

Error message as follows:

`Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.; duration or timeout: 203 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.14.0', revision: '14955', time: '2011-11-29 11:43:45'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_30'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver`

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be avoided by using the following code while initializing the FireFox Driver

```java
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

If the Driver is initialized like this then the Actions work properly.

Comment: Hi Hari, Thanks for your reply , actually the problem was of OS only , I already done profiling of browsers like for IE , HTMLUnit , Chrome and remote also .There was one single test case which requires wait, I added implicit wait for each element in the test class which resolved the problem.